# Prove by induction.

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I'm working on an assignment and stuck on the same question for the last three hours. I have no idea how I'm suppose to factor and prove this question by induction.

Use mathematical induction on positive integer n to prove each of the following where $$n\ge1$$

$$
1^2 + 4^2 + 7^2 + \cdots + (3n-2)^2 = \frac{1}{2}n(6n^2 -3n- 1)
$$

I got as far as evaluating:

$$(3k - 2)^2 = \frac{1}{2}k(6k^2 - 3k -1)$$

and replacing with k+1

$$(3(k+1) -2)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(k+1)[6(k+1)^2-3(k+1)-1]\\\Longleftrightarrow(3k +1)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(k+1)(6k^2+9k+2)$$

I'm now having trouble proving the induction part.

$$\frac{1}{2}k(6k^2 - 3k -1) +(3k +1)^2 =? \frac{1}{2}(k+1)(6k^2+9k+2)$$

I must be overthinking this, or doing something wrong.

Comment: Just multiply out both sides. The equality is true. [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F2)k(6k%5E2%E2%88%923k%E2%88%921)%2B(3k%2B1)%5E2%3D1%2F2(k%2B1)(6k%5E2%2B9k%2B2)&t=crmtb01 ]

Comment: Your third equation is wrong(but the idea is right): You omitted the previous terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2}k(6k^2 - 3k -1) +(3k +1)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(k(6k^2 - 3k -1) +2(3k +1)^2)= \frac{1}{2}(6k^3 - 3k^2 -k +18k^2+12k+2)=\frac{1}{2}(6k^3 +15k^2+11k+2)=\frac{1}{2}(k+1)(6k^2+9k+2)$$

Comment: How did you know (k+1) was a factor of $$6k^3 + 15k^2+11k+2$$?

Comment: Just multiplied $\frac{1}{2}(k+1)(6k^2+9k+2)$ to get $\frac{1}{2}(6k^3+15k^2+11k+2)$

Comment: Thanks, makes a little more sense now.